# How to config Vino to let vncviewer show the hostname of server instead of "LibVNCServer "?

Tags: configuration, vnc

When vncviewer connected a vncserver which is on Windows, the title of vncviewer will be the hostname of windows server.

But when vncviewer connected to vino vnc server on Linux, the title of vncviewer is always "LibVNCServer", is there any way to display hostname of linux server on vncviewer title ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set the hostname as the parameter `-name` when staring the Unix/Linux VNC server.

For instance I start my vncserver as

```
/usr/bin/vncserver -name HATARI -geometry 800x600 -httpport 8080
```

Comment: thanks for the information. i prefer Vino than vncserver itself, because vncserver does not give the control of real console desktop. i havn't privilege to create new tag, so i choosed `vnc` tag.